# UIPopoverPresentationController on the iphone (6+ / 6s+ / 7+) problems of landscape

Tags: controller, popover, landscape, presentation

[image]
As shown above, when the landscape UIPopoverPresentationController to be such a display

Now this problem only on the 5.5 -inch phones (landscape)

On the 4.7 -inch phones will display correctly，The following figure：
[image]

This is my source code：

`- (void)buttonClick:(UIButton *)sender{
    self.buttonPopVC = [[PopoverViewController alloc] init];
    self.buttonPopVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    self.buttonPopVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _button; 
    self.buttonPopVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = _button.bounds;
    self.buttonPopVC.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp; 
    self.buttonPopVC.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.buttonPopVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}`

`- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}`

`- (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController{
    return NO;

}`

`- (CGSize)preferredContentSize {
    if (self.presentingViewController && self.tableView != nil) {
        CGSize tempSize = self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size;
        tempSize.width = 150;
        CGSize size = [self.tableView sizeThatFits:tempSize];
        return size;
    }else {
        return [super preferredContentSize];
    }
} 
- (void)setPreferredContentSize:(CGSize)preferredContentSize{
    super.preferredContentSize = preferredContentSize;
}`

Could you tell me the solution?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `traitCollection` variation of the `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` delegate method:

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController 
-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller 
traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Either instead of, or with the one you have already:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```